# g++ register allocation

Tags: c++, g++, cpu-registers

Is there a safe way in g++ to force a variable to be in a certain register when a function is called? This function contains inline-asm-code that assumes inputs in certain registers.

I tried to declare local variables to be in fixed registers (`register int x asm ("$10")`) and pass them to the function, but `-O3` messes it up.

I don't want to reserve registers for the whole program by declaring global variables in registers.

Answer (score 1):

I you want the parameters of a function to be passed in registers, you can do something like this:

```
int __attribute__((fastcall)) foo(register int a, register int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

- `__attribute__((fastcall))` means that the first two parameters of the function are passed in ECX and EDX respectively.
- The `register` keyword is used to prevent GCC from copying the parameters to the stack once the function is entered.

I found this to work reliably across different `-O` levels.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asm volatile` inline assembly blocks, like explained in [this page](http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4).

Comment: `asm volatile` doesn't work for variable declaration (or did you mean to use it at another point?)

Comment: @Thomas: I think it's not `asm volatile` itself, but the other information on that page, that you need to look at.

Comment: why don't you prepare the values in inline assembly as well?

Comment: @Ben: I read that whole page (input/output operands, modifiers, constraints,...) but could not find options to specify registers. I could imagine a non-optimal solution that specifies input operands and includes inline asm commands to put them in the appropriate registers.

Comment: @stupid: Because the code block to calculate those values is much more complicated.

Comment: @Thomas: yea, but you can still count it in C++ and then store the final values into registers with assembly..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extended Assembly.
This is for gcc, it should work: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html
You can use input register that will be filled by the variable you want.
Or you may refer to the C++ variable directly by its name in the inline asm code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass variables declared with explicit registers directly to the inline asm statement; the register must be specified in the function containing the asm statement.